# json multi array echo

Tags: php, arrays, json

with:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20startDate=%272014-01-01%27%20and%20endDate=%272014-01-10%27%20and%20symbol=%27YHOO%27");
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);

/*
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $myArray );
echo "</pre>";
*/

echo $myArray['query']['results']['quote'][0]['Close']," DayX";
?>
```

i can read out the closing-number for the first day.

-> how can i read out ALL entries for 'Close'? -> in this example it would be:

```
echo $myArray['query']['results']['quote'][0]['Close']," Day1";
echo $myArray['query']['results']['quote'][1]['Close']," Day2";
echo $myArray['query']['results']['quote'][2]['Close']," Day3";
...
echo $myArray['query']['results']['quote'][6]['Close']," Day7";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php???

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a `foreach` loop to do that.

```
foreach ($myArray['query']['results']['quote'] as $k => $v) {
  echo $v['Close'] . " Day" . ($k+1) . "<br />";
}
```

Having `<br />` at the end of each line will add a line break, assuming this is being `echo`ed to the browser;